# Cant navigate to php.net on specific device

Tags: google-chrome, navigation

actually am trying to navigate to php.net on an specific device in my LAN and also tried to ping php.net and there was no answer
[image: PING]

The answer from Google Chrome was this, using www and without
[image: CHROME]

Actually i only know about this site that i cant navigate to.

Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

IPS network error fixed days after question made, there was not a solution by software changes